# Custom post type - posts list - white screen of death

Tags: custom-post-types, fatal-error

i am getting a weird error - white screen in the list of posts
for a specific Custom post type (just for that one)

- tried deactivating all the plugins
- tried checking for error (debugging = true)

**Still nothing**
the page just doesnt echos anything... (nothing in source too)

I am talking about such a url in the admin:
http://www.example.co.il/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=submodelscpt

**Here is register_post_type part i am using:**

```
function register_submodelcpt() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => __('Sub Models', THEME_NAME),
        'singular_name'         => __('Sub Models', THEME_NAME),
        'add_new'               => __('New Model', THEME_NAME),
        'add_new_item'          => __('Add new Model', THEME_NAME),
        'edit_item'             => __('Edit Model', THEME_NAME),
        'new_item'              => __('New Model', THEME_NAME),
        'all_items'             => __('All Sub Models', THEME_NAME),
        'view_item'             => __('Watch Model', THEME_NAME),
        'search_items'          => __('Search Models', THEME_NAME),
        'not_found'             =>  __('No Models found', THEME_NAME),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __('No Models found in trash', THEME_NAME), 
        'parent_item_colon'     => '',
        'menu_name'             => __('Sub Models', THEME_NAME),

    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'public'                => true,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'show_ui'               => true, 
        'show_in_menu'          => true, 
        'query_var'             => true,
        'rewrite'               => array('slug' => 'submodels'),
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
        'has_archive'           => true, 
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'menu_icon'             => get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/cpt/subcars.png',            
        'supports'              => array('title', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'page-attributes')
    ); 
    register_post_type('submodelscpt',$args);
}
add_action('init', 'register_submodelcpt');
```

Did anyone encounter such an issuse?
can you think of a reason this might happen?

**Another weird thing**
when i change this:
http://www.example.co.il/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=submodelscpt

**To this:**
http://www.example.co.il/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=submodelscpt&orderby=date&order=desc

The posts list loads correctly...

Comment: there's nothing in your included code that would cause this, verify you don't have something interfering with queries- `pre_get_posts`, query filters, etc..

Comment: thanks milo... searched for pre_get_posts across files and couldnt find anything - this is weird! ;<( thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Agree with @Milo, must be something acting on query. Note that there are tons of filter that act on query, not only `pre_get_posts`. However, if your debug is active and you get white screen with no errors I think there must be an `exit` or a `die`, try to search for them.

Comment: thats a gr8 idea! will do G.M thanks for your input

Comment: Any progress on this? Having the same issue.

Comment: Hey nick, after i removed some custom columns for that custom post type this weirdly fixed itself. after that i recreated that code again and it worked.

Comment: @Nic its solved - just to let you know ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok... for anyone visiting this post - i have found the solution...
i actually encountered this issues again (when a site has a lot of pages)

**The issue is this line when registering a custom post type:**

```
'hierarchical'          => true,
```

**All you need to do is to change it to false!**

```
'hierarchical'          => false,
```

**Explenation:**
It appears that when "hierarchical" is set to true, each post behaves like a page. I am quoting here so I don't really understand why it matters but changing this line remove the problem.

Answer (score 8):

This is to extend your own answer:

> It appears that when "hierarchical" is set to true, each post behaves like a page. I am quoting here so I don't really understand why it matters but changing this line remove the problem.

Here is what the codex says about the `hierarchical` parameter

> **hierarchical**
>
> (boolean) (optional) Whether the post type is hierarchical (e.g. page). Allows Parent to be specified. The 'supports' parameter should contain 'page-attributes' to show the parent select box on the editor page.
>
> Default: false
>
> **Note:** this parameter was planned for Pages. Be careful, when choosing it for your custom post type - if you are planning to have many entries (say - over 100), you will run into memory issue. With this parameter set to true WordPress will fetch all entries of that particular post type, together with all meta data, on each administration page load for your post type.

When a custom post type is set as hierarchichal, its behavior will be same as the build in post type `page`. Like pages, Wordpress tries to build a tree to display the correct hierarchical tree with parent-child relationships in the back end. As you might have noticed, pages are not sorted by date in the back end, but by this parent-child relationship. This behavior you can easily see when visiting the `Page` page in back end.

This operation is very expensive as Wordpress needs to get each page ( or post from a hierarchical post type ) on **every page load** and then look for that specific page's/post's parent and child pages to build a the correct tree for that specific page/post. If you have a large amount of pages or posts in your hierarchical custom post type, the query simply becomes to big and exceeds memory limits or times out, which leads to a fatal error, hence the WSOD.

Non-hierarchical post types like the build in post type `post` don't have such a hierarchy as non-hierarchical post type posts can't have child posts. Because there is no need to build a parent-child relationship tree (for obvious reasons), Wordpress simply queries 20 (*IIRC*) posts per page ordered by date in the back end and displays them in contrast to hierarchical post type posts where Wordpress has to query **all** posts at once, build a tree and then display only an x amount on a posts grouped according to their parent-child relationship. You can check this behavior in the `Post` page in the back end

So setting a custom post type to hierarchical tells Wordpress that it should build a list/tree of posts grouped by their parent-child relationship and return those posts in that configuration. Setting a custom post type to non-hierarchical, you are telling Wordpress to skip the whole relationship thing and to just return an x amount of posts per page ordered by post date

I hope this make a bit more sense to you why you should avoid making custom post types hierarchical, and why that is also stated in the codex

Comment: very cool @pietergoosen thanks a lot for sharing - i hate just doing without the why ;)

Comment: My pleasure. Ejoy :-)

Answer (score 7):

I just want to add to the answers by @SagiveSEO and @PieterGoosen.

There's also a potential *performance killer* regarding the *hierarchial* post types:

Namely the **parent page dropdown** box that uses `wp_dropdown_pages()`.

It's currently very unefficent as it loads (almost) all the pages into the select dropdown box.

So if we have a site with many pages, then this can hurt performance.

Just imagine a site with 1 million pages ;-)

This was reported 6 years ago with the ticket [#9864](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9864). It's still open so you can still contribute to the proposed auto-complete solution.

### Update:

I just wanted to mention some helpful filters:

- `wp_dropdown_pages` -- a output filter for the `wp_dropdown_pages()` function. Might be used to append or echo some extra HTML if needed.
- `get_pages` -- because `wp_dropdown_pages()` calls the `get_pages()` function.
- `page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args` -- a filter for the arguments to `wp_dropdown_pages()` on the `post.php/post-new.php` screens for hierarchical post types.
- `quick_edit_dropdown_pages_args` -- a filter for the argument to `wp_dropdown_pages()` on the `edit.php` screens for hierararchical post types.

that could be used to address the problem.

It's possible to modify the output of `wp_dropdown_pages()` on the `post.php` screen with:

```
add_filter( 'page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args', function( $dropdown_args, $post )
{
    if( 'page' === $post->post_type )
    {
        $dropdown_args['number']       = 10; // Limit the number of pages
        $dropdown_args['hierarchical'] = 0;  // Keep it non-hierarchical 
        $dropdown_args['offset']       = 1;  // Ideal for pagination
    }
    return $dropdown_args;
}, 10, 2 );
```

and similarly for the `edit.php` screen for *pages*:

```
add_filter( 'quick_edit_dropdown_pages_args', function( $dropdown_args )
{
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if( 'edit-page' === $screen->id )
    {
        $dropdown_args['number']       = 10; // Limit the number of pages
        $dropdown_args['hierarchical'] = 0;  // Keep it non-hierarchical
        $dropdown_args['offset']        = 1;  // Suitable for pagination
    }
    return $dropdown_args;
} );
```

Note that the second input argument (`$post`) is not available for this filter callback.

It's of course possible to just remove the page attributes support:

```
add_action( 'init', function()
{
    remove_post_type_support( $post_type = 'page', 'page-attributes' );

} );
```

but then we might as well just use a non-hierarchical post type instead ;-)

**List parents with ajax pagination?**

It should be possible, with the help of the above filters, to create a paginated (non-hierarchical) list of parents, that would be updated via ajax. Maybe the select box options could be updated, to keep the current layout. This would probably? be a different approach than the suggested (on core trac) parent search box, with auto completion.

Comment: Thanks for that info. Something to look into in near future ;-)

Comment: I just discovered this few weeks ago, when I got to work on an install with few thousand pages. I was surprised to see that the parent page dropdown box had thousands of options ;-) This is also part of the *Quick Edit* in the `edit.php` screen @PieterGoosen

Comment: That is insane. Never dealt with this many pages on one install.

Comment: yes and with the current core state I wouldn't recommend using more than ~100 pages, unless you got a good server => we just have to find a way to use non hierarchial posts instead of pages for large number of items ;-)

Comment: I wonder how possible it would be to properly create a cache and update it whenever pages are published, edited, or deleted. I mean, instead of flushing the cache, you can simply update it to add or remove the appropriate details. As for the dropdown issue, I don't have any idea how this might be solved with a large amount of pages.

Comment: maybe if the backend would keep all the objects in memory and only sync with the database through some clever "diff" ;-) I think one proposed solution to the `wp_dropdown_pages()` problem, is to use a search text box with an ajax auto completion instead of the current dropdown box,  when the number of pages are "large". @PieterGoosen

Comment: I just want to note, just because everyone at this time and age can dump his/her crap in a unstructured stream of consciousness fashion on to the world, having hundreds maybe even thousands of pages in a hierarchical structure is something very plausible. Apparently nobody using WordPress has a need for it and it seems obvious that WP just isn't the right tool for it. Which could be the end of it, but actually it is a disgrace - and kind of a conscious decision and as such shaping WP and its image - to allow this "bug" to live for such long time. @PieterGoosen

Comment: Seems like I have my serious "philosophical" day today.. :D So ignore me, its just a general note for anybody who cares. @PieterGoosen

Comment: @ialocin anything informative is appreciated, even philosophical views ;-)

Comment: Don't know if it qualifies as informative, but thanks anyway. @PieterGoosen

Answer (score -1):

Here is a full example from wordpress codex

```
add_action( 'init', 'codex_book_init' );
function codex_book_init() {
$labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Books', 'post type general name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Book', 'post type singular name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'menu_name'          => _x( 'Books', 'admin menu', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Book', 'add new on admin bar', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All Books', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Books', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Books:', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No books found.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No books found in Trash.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' )
);

$args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'book' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
);

register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}
```

Comment: whats up with the copy and paste? why did you paste this code here?

Comment: Sorry dint see your code i was checking it from adroid app but dont know why it hides the content sometime and sometime it strech it very anoing