# Decrease edit.php and post-new.php load

Tags: wp-admin, performance

On a new install with default Twenty Fifteen theme and no activated plugins.
I used Really Simple CSV Importer to import ~4000 pages with title and one word content for each. This is to have my pages ready for use with Advanced Custom Fields (pages will have dozen text areas metaboxes, not really using any advanced ACF features like repeaters or anything)

edit.php and post-new.php take a long time to load on a good, not crowded SSD, high RAM server (confirmed this with others on the server and my host).

I guess the number of pages are the factor. I wanted to see what effect deactivating ACF and all other plugins have. No noticeable difference, I turned off all screen options and reduced the 'Number of items per page' too. So now the edit.php?post_type=page only shows pages titles and post-new.php?post_type=page only the title and content boxes and Publish buttons.

When I looked at the page source I guess I see the issue, on both edit.php and post-new.php after all I have done above (deactivate, turn off, etc.)  a list of all my pages are loaded like:

```
<div id="pageparentdiv" class="postbox  hide-if-js" >
<div class="handlediv" title="Click to toggle"><br /></div><h3 class='hndle'>          
<span>Page Attributes</span></h3>
<div class="inside">
<p><strong>Parent</strong></p>
<label class="screen-reader-text" for="parent_id">Parent</label>
<select name='parent_id' id='parent_id'>
<option value="0">Main Page (no parent)</option>
<option class="level-0" value="3">Page 1</option>
<option class="level-0" value="4">Page 2</option>
.
.
.
<option class="level-0" value="4300">Page 4000</option>
</select>
</label>
```

Is it possible to not have that load every time? If so, using a filter or plugin?

Comment: It's not quite clear at which stage do you have the issue. Before/during/after the import process?

Comment: I thought it best to explain my situation so that it is known that I have many imported pages, nothing activated and many screen options turned off. 
The issue occurs when running WordPress with that many pages, that is going to wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page and wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page both are extremely slow and seem resource intensive as well. I guess it is due the page list loading (but the list is only visible in the source) and I was wondering if the behaviour can be changed.

Comment: This is a known "feature"/bug - reported 6 years ago - see above link.

Comment: Very similar if not the same indeed. I wonder if there is a workaround for the current version of WordPress.

Comment: There's a workaround, like removing the metabox, would that be an option? Or change to non-hierarchical post type.

Comment: The page list -code I posted above - is visible in (browser's) view source only, that seems to be a source of confusion. I have set edit.php to show 5 per page but there is that code loading a 4000+ list in the source. There is no metabox left to remove from edit.php. I have also removed all metaboxes I can post-new.php but when I view source it has the same lines of code.  Would you be able to tell me, if there is a query or way to set hierarchical to false?

Comment: If you can't use a non-hierarchical post type instead, I updated my answer [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/187717/26350), for some other ideas.

Comment: The two filters in the answer linked have really improved the page load time, if not peak memory usage. Using the Query Monitor plugin these are edit.php before and after numbers respectively (Page generation time; peak memory; database query time; number of queries):   
18.3070 218,912kB 0.2559 21 ---> 
2.0571 218,900kB 0.2562 21