# Structuring 3K pages in Wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I am about to convert an old site that have approx. 3000 pages to WordPress for a museum. Rather minimalistic layout: navigation to the left, a main column and a sidebar.

Since almost all material is "static" I am leaning towards using post type Page together with custom categories for manage the hierarchy of the site.

Also I would like to be able to set an special index-page for every category without having to make an custom template.

Has any one experience of working with a really big site (content wise)?

How to you structure the pages?

How do you handle the permalinks? By post title and category? Since it's more of less static content I feel that I cannot use dates.

Any hints och links are much appreciated!

Regards, J

Comment: There's a potential performance problem, with large  number of  hierarchical cpt, regarding parent selection. More about that [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169582/custom-post-type-posts-list-white-screen-of-death/187717).

Comment: birgie, thanks for the link! This is what I needed. Post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.