# wp_insert_post extremely slow on big table, direct query very fast

Tags: wp-insert-post

My posts table is about 600K, and I don't consider this big at all. Anyway wp_insert_post is becoming very slow. I am trying to import a huge list of hotel information into Posts. The list is about 1500K big. Inserting posts starts nicely with 200-400 posts per second but it dramatically drops down to abt 20-10 posts per second when it reaches 400K posts.

When I do a direct query on the posts table it is inserting 400 posts per second again. So my conclusion is that wp_insert_post is slowing things down considerably.

I tried some 'tricks' to improve wp_insert_post speed such as :

```
wp_defer_term_counting( false );
wp_defer_comment_counting( false );
$wpdb->query( 'SET autocommit = 0;' );
```

and after the bulk import:

```
wp_defer_term_counting( true );
wp_defer_comment_counting( true );
$wpdb->query( 'SET autocommit = 1;' );
$wpdb->query( 'COMMIT;' );
```

but that doesn't help improving the speed of insert, actually the improvement is none.

Can someone please explain to me what 'check' in the wp_insert_post function is slowing it down?

Is it column 'post_name' AKA slug ? it must be unique, right? Are there any other columns that are checked on?

I would like to know what is checked, or what NEEDS to be checked because I am seriously thinking of overriding wp_insert_post function with my own to speed things up.

thanks in advance

edit - added my loop :

```
foreach($hotels as $key => $hotel) {

    $slug  = $hotel->HotelName;
    $title = $hotel->HotelName;


if ($hotel->translation == NULL) {
    $description = $hotel->Overview;
    } else {
    $description = $hotel->translation;
    }

    $hotel_id = wp_insert_post(
        array(
            //'ID'              =>  $hotel->id,
            'post_mime_type'    =>  $hotel->id,
            'comment_status'    =>  'closed',
            'ping_status'       =>  'closed',
            'post_author'       =>  $author_id,
            'post_name'         =>  $slug,
            'post_title'        =>  $title,
            'post_status'       =>  'publish',
            'post_type'         =>  'hotel',
            'post_content'      =>  $description, )
    );

    }
```

Comment: How are you looping through and running your queries? Knowing that might help to point out any issues as more often than not what you are seeing is due to not freeing up resources properly.

Comment: So you're importing 1.5 Million posts? I think you should do the `wp_defer_term_counting` vice versa, i.e. first `true` before the run and then `false` after it - I think *defer* means *to postpone something*.

Comment: yeah you are correct. But anyway wp_defer_term_counting doesn't apply to my loop because I am not using any terms. Those will come when I maximized the speed insertion of just simple posts. The function wp_insert_post is extremely slow, and I wonder why.

Comment: Are you doing it on vanila wordpress, with no plugins active?

Comment: yep, just my own plugin which hooks into nothing.

Comment: I wonder if you did try this on InnoDB with commits e.g. every 500 posts as suggested by Otto [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102349/faster-way-to-wp-insert-post-add-post-meta-in-bulk#comment141276_102361).

Comment: Hi Birgire, the issue is not that inserting the data into table posts is slow. The issue is that checking for unique SLUG is extremely slow. Before every insert WP checks if the SLUG provided is unique, and if not it will add -01 or -02 etc etc.

Comment: I know for a fact having indices for a table will slow down the inserts. Should you temporarily remove the indices then add them back once you're done?

Comment: If the post status is *draft*, then the slug check should be skipped, but when we publish later the slug check is performed. A hacky workaround would be to publish these imported draft-posts (change the post status and slug) via custom SQL queries. But that needs a special care.

Answer (score 5):

you should revers the code you should add this befor the import

```
wp_defer_term_counting( true );
wp_defer_comment_counting( true );
```

don't set it false and after the import you set it true you must do the oppsite thing
i had the same issue to insert 50 posts  it took about 7 mintues after i added this code befor the wp_insert_post it took just 7 seconds
and you can add this too

```
define( 'WP_IMPORTING', true );
```

and after you imported the post add this and run the script

```
wp_defer_term_counting( false );
wp_defer_comment_counting( false );
```

Answer (score 3):

This will insert posts directly, and a fair bit faster than wp_insert_post. However, generating the guid does not work yet. You have to be a lot more careful with the input you pass in, and it won't run any hooks that normally run on wp_insert_post. It might be useful for somebody, but I **strongly advise using it with caution (and fixing the guid first).**

```
/**
 * todo: The guid column does not work. You must not use this class without fixing it first.
 *
 * Insert posts fast, hopefully.
 *
 * Unlike wp_insert_post(), its not used to update posts (what a surprise?).
 *
 * Skips a lot of the logic from inside wp_insert_post() in such a way that
 * hopefully, most of the time, you end up with the same result...
 *
 * USE WITH CAUTION.
 *
 * Sanitize and Validate all of your own data before passing it in.
 *
 * Will not stop you from doing bad things.
 *
 * Lastly, it will not trigger any of the normal hooks that WordPress
 * triggers when inserting a post. This could cause some serious
 * issues, depending on the post type. For example, if you
 * use this with woocommerce, I have no idea what might NOT
 * get run by using this as opposed to wp_insert_post, and
 * whether or not it will lead to any serious issues.
 *
 * todo: maybe we can look at running some of the same hooks that are inside of wp_insert_post.
 *
 * https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176644/wp-insert-post-extremely-slow-on-big-table-direct-query-very-fast
 * https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/349599/wordpress-insert-post-without-actions-hooks
 *
 * Class WPSE_Post_Inserter
 */
Class WPSE_Post_Inserter
{

    const DATABASE_DATE_FORMAT = "Y-m-d H:i:s";

    // WP specifies column defaults in SQL (as expected),
    // therefore, we should leave fields as STRICTLY NULL
    // when we want to ensure that default SQL values are used.
    // when they are strictly null, we will not pass them into
    // the update statement.

    public $post_author;
    public $post_date;
    public $post_date_gmt;
    public $post_content;
    public $post_excerpt;
    public $post_status = "publish";
    public $comment_status = "closed";
    public $ping_status = "closed";
    public $post_password;
    public $post_name;

    // i'm just not even going to include these, even though they are columns in the database.
//    public $to_ping;
//    public $pinged;


    // if you are going to set dates manually, check the helper methods to do so,
    // otherwise, ensure you use the correct format, and set all 4 columns.
    public $post_modified;
    public $post_modified_gmt;
    public $post_content_filtered;
    public $post_parent;
    public $guid;
    public $menu_order;
    public $post_type;
    public $post_mime_type;

    // no point including this for now...
    // public $comment_count;

    /**
     * Accept only the args we always expect..
     *
     * GPPI_Post_Inserter constructor.
     * @param $post_type
     * @param $post_title
     */
    public function __construct($post_type, $post_title, $post_status = 'publish', $logged_in_user_as_post_author = false)
    {

        $this->post_type = $post_type;
        $this->post_title = $post_title;
        $this->post_status = $post_status;

        if ($logged_in_user_as_post_author) {
            $this->post_author = (int)get_current_user_id();
            $this->post_author = $this->post_author ? $this->post_author : null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * One way you might want to use this class. Right now, all properties are public,
     * so you can kind of do whatever you like and then just cross your fingers
     * when you run ->commit().
     */
    public static function example_usage()
    {

        try {

            // constructor accepts the fields that we generally always want to include.
            $obj = new WPSE_Post_Inserter('product', "Product 123", "publish", false);

            // a bunch of other fields are set manually, by accessing the properties directly.
            // its your job to sanitize and validate the data here. The commit function will
            // do almost none of that.
            $obj->post_content = "...";

            // commit will try to take care of the rest, like post_name, post_date, guid.
            $post_id = $obj->commit();

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // ....
        }
    }

    /**
     * An array of column names which must also be the exact
     * same as class property names.
     *
     * Its possible that this is the same as get_object_vars( $this ).
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function get_post_field_names()
    {
        return [
            'post_author',
            'post_date',
            'post_date_gmt',
            'post_content',
            'post_excerpt',
            'post_status',
            'comment_status',
            'ping_status',
            'post_password',
            'post_name',
            'post_modified',
            'post_modified_gmt',
            'post_content_filtered',
            'post_parent',
            'guid',
            'menu_order',
            'post_type',
            'post_mime_type',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Validate a few fields, Auto generate a few more, then run some *basic* sanitation on
     * some of the fields, then insert into the database.
     */
    public function commit()
    {

        global $wpdb;

        // silently re-assign post name if its not already valid ...
        if (!$this->post_name || !WPSE_Post_Name_Cache::is_unique($this->post_name)) {
            $this->post_name = $this->set_post_name($this->post_title ? $this->post_title : $this->post_name);
        }

        // seems impossible that this could still occur, but maybe somehow it could.
        // even if the title was empty.. the suffix will get added..
        if (!$this->post_name || !WPSE_Post_Name_Cache::is_unique($this->post_name)) {
            throw new Exception("Post name cannot be generated or is not unique: " . $this->post_name);
        }

        // set current timestamp by default.
        if (!$this->post_date) {
            $this->set_date_via_timestamp();
        }

        // its possible that the modified dates are actually not required,
        // as WP seems to at least allow this for auto draft post status I think.
        if (!$this->post_date || !$this->post_date_gmt) {
            throw new Exception("Both post insert dates are required");
        }

        // not worrying about invalid post types, there is nothing wrong
        // with having un-registered post types in the database...
        // in fact throwing the exception will save you from WP defaulting
        // this value to 'post', which I would bet, you don't want.
        if (!$this->post_type) {
            throw new Exception("Post type should not be empty");
        }

        // probably you wouldn't want to pass this in beforehand
        if (!$this->guid) {

            // build stdClass object containing all of the fields
            // we currently have. This tricks get_post() into
            // thinking we gave it a valid post object. The theory
            // is that it will generate the permalink according
            // to the chosen permalink structure in the settings,
            // based on the properties of the post object.
            // or, will it just try to hit the database anyways,
            // and then fail
            $obj = new stdClass();
            foreach ($this->get_post_field_names() as $field) {
                $obj->{$field} = $this->{$field};
            }

            // hard to know that this won't just go and hit the database anyways...
            // todo: This does not generate a guid! It seems to return nothing.
            // todo: if we update the guid after the post is inserted, will it work? I haven't looked into this yet.
            $this->guid = get_the_permalink(get_post($obj));
        }

        $data = [];
        foreach ($this->get_post_field_names() as $field) {
            $data[$field] = isset($this->{$field}) ? $this->{$field} : null;
        }

        // omit strictly null values and let the database use default values.
        $data = array_filter($data, function ($value) {
            return $value !== null;
        });

        // this accepts an array or object and will sanitize all
        // post fields for database storage.
        $data = sanitize_post($data, 'db');

        // the above function tracks the current state of the items sanitization...
        // don't send that to sql.
        unset($data['filter']);

        if (!$wpdb->insert($wpdb->posts, $data)) {
            return false;
        }

        $post_id = (int)$wpdb->insert_id;
        return $post_id;
    }

    /**
     * Appends -1, -2, -3, etc. until it finds a unique post_name, after turning
     * the post title into a slug. 
     * 
     * todo: why would I write a function that both generates the post slug and then sets it at the same time?
     * todo: would be better to separate this logic.
     *
     * @param $post_title
     * @param null $loop_counter_limit - probably, you don't need to worry about this.
     * @return string
     */
    public function set_post_name($post_title, $loop_counter_limit = null)
    {

        if (!$post_title) {
            $base_name = 'no-title';
        } else {
            $base_name = sanitize_title($post_title);
        }

        $counter = 0;

        do {

            $counter++;
            if ($loop_counter_limit && $loop_counter_limit > $counter) {
                $post_name = uniqid() . random_int(10e8, 10e9);
            } else {
                $suffix = $counter > 0 ? "-" . $counter : "";
                
                $post_name = _truncate_post_slug($base_name . $suffix, 200 - strlen($suffix));
            }

        } while (!WPSE_Post_Name_Cache::is_unique($post_name));

        return $post_name;
    }

    /**
     * If you use time() or current_time( 'timestamp', 1 ), then $is_gmt should be true.
     *
     * If you use current_time( 'timestamp' ) or current_time( 'timestamp', 0 ), gmt should
     * be false...
     *
     * However, pass in $time = null to use the current time.... you only need to set
     * the time to use a date in the past (or future), although, I won't compare
     * dates in the future to set the post status of future.
     *
     * So.. if you are using a timestamp in the past, there's a good chance its already in GMT,
     * if its not, then you'll probably want to convert it that.
     *
     * To be honest, if you have to use anything other than the current time, then
     * your probably going to get confused using this function.
     *
     * @param null $time
     * @param $is_gmt
     */
    public function set_date_via_timestamp($time = null, $is_gmt = true)
    {

        if ($time === null) {
            $time = time();
            $is_gmt = true;
        }

        $this->post_date = self::date_from_time($time, $is_gmt, false);
        $this->post_date_gmt = self::date_from_time($time, $is_gmt, true);

        // modified date equals insertion date
        $this->post_modified = $this->post_date;
        $this->post_modified_gmt = $this->post_date_gmt;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param null $time
     * @param bool $is_gmt - if using time(), set to true, if using current_time( 'timestamp' ), set to false.
     * @param bool $return_gmt
     * @return false|string
     */
    public static function date_from_time($time = null, $is_gmt = true, $return_gmt = true)
    {

        if ($time === null) {
            $time = time();
            $is_gmt = true;
        }

        $offset = get_option('gmt_offset') * HOUR_IN_SECONDS;

        if ($is_gmt && $return_gmt) {
            return date(self::DATABASE_DATE_FORMAT, $time);
        } else if ($is_gmt && !$return_gmt) {
            return date(self::DATABASE_DATE_FORMAT, $time + $offset);
        } else if ($return_gmt && !$is_gmt) {
            return date(self::DATABASE_DATE_FORMAT, $time - $offset);
        } else {
            return date(self::DATABASE_DATE_FORMAT, $time);
        }
    }
}
```

The above class depends on this one:

```
/**
 * Cache all post names used in the database.
 *
 * Make sure you register new ones if you insert any posts.
 *
 * Lets you very quickly check if a post name exists, many times
 * in the same script. If you are using it to insert a post manually,
 * be aware that wp_insert_post does a lot more logic than just
 * checking if the post name is in use. It also compares different
 * post types and checks things such as page hierarchy so that the
 * post_name column is not truly unique.
 *
 * Class WPSE_Post_Name_Cache
 */
Class WPSE_Post_Name_Cache
{

    /**
     * Must be strictly null or array of post names.
     *
     * The array is INDEXED by post name, which makes the
     * lookup much faster. isset > in_array in this case.
     *
     * @var
     */
    private static $post_names;

    /**
     * Runs a query on first call to setup the data.
     */
    public static function lazy_load()
    {
        if (self::$post_names === null) {

            global $wpdb;
            $post_names = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT post_name FROM {$wpdb->posts}", 0);

            foreach ($post_names as $index => $post_name) {
                self::$post_names[$post_name] = 1;
            }

        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if no posts use that name.
     *
     * @param $post_name
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function is_unique($post_name)
    {    
        self::lazy_load();
        return !isset(self::$post_names[$post_name]);
    }

    /**
     * Maybe easier to reason about like this, idk.
     *
     * @param $post_name
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function exists($post_name)
    {
        return !self::is_unique($post_name);
    }

    /**
     * Send all new post names here otherwise, is_unique() might
     * return the wrong value.
     *
     * @param $post_name
     */
    public static function register_new_post_name($post_name)
    {
        self::lazy_load();
        self::$post_names[$post_name] = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tested this approach compared to the others. It is around 40% quicker!

Answer (score 2):

Try modifying the database to improve the lookup speed of the post_name field...

```
ALTER TABLE `wp_posts` ADD INDEX (`post_name`);
```

You want to avoid writing your own `wp_insert_post()` replacement as there are little tricks that occur in unexpected places that become a real headache to debug later on.

Comment: I thought that Indexes make reading data faster, but will make writing to the database slower because the index has to be rebuilt.

Comment: @Mr.Me In this case the issue was not with how fast the inserts occur, but with how fast the `wp_insert_post()` function performs. Since the `wp_insert_post()` function is ~500 lines of validation to ensure that fields are properly filled the slowdown occurs due to those validation routines. In particular the search through the existing list of slugs (the "post_name" field) gets much slower as the number of post entries increases. By creating an index on that field you increase the rate of those look-ups and thus make the execution faster overall.

Comment: In WordPress 5.9 (and well before?), there is already an index on column 'post_name':  https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_posts