# Set post terms for multiple posts

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have got array of post ids and I want to add term to each of this post. It could be done by loop over each post id and using `wp_set_post_terms`, for example

```
$term_id = 10; // for example
$taxonomy = 'my_custom_taxonomy';
$post_ids = array(70, 68, 65, 64, 63, 21, 20, 19, 9);

foreach ($post_ids as $post_id) {
    // true at end means 'append'
    wp_set_post_terms($post_id, $term_id, $taxonomy, true);
}
```

but this is not efficient for a lot of posts (I want to do this for over 500 posts and it takes to much time). Is there any faster way to do this task?

Comment: too much time for the server ? or too much time for the user ? you can try do this by lots with WP Cron

Comment: To much time for server. Admin clicks on button, it redirects to admin-ajax.php page which do this task based on term_id passed as `$_GET` parameter.

Comment: then you can do it with WP Cron in many times. read this : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event

Comment: i don't want to schedule this task. I wonder if there is some one-line, optimized function to do this, like `wp_set_post_terms` used with multiple term ids for one post (`wp_set_post_terms($post_id, array(1, 2, 3...));`)

Comment: Defer term counting and transactions come to mind

Comment: @birgire what do you mean by `transactions`? MySQL transactions or something different?

Comment: MySQL transactions (InnoDB) - Similar as mentioned [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/102361/26350)